# Guake background no more transparent in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, transparency, guake

After upgrading from saucy to trusty, the Guake pull-down window is displaying the wallpaper as the background.

What I want is that it should be 50% transparent and display whichever window I am working on currently below the guake terminal. (like it used to on Saucy)

I checked the settings and they are in line with the expected transparent behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Transparency effects require desktop composition to be enabled to work.  Install compizconfig settings manager `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` and then open it, go "Accessibility" and I think "Opacity" is the correct option to enable this, however I'm at work and not able to verify this at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Ibaile200's answer worked for me.  Specifically, I installed compiz:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz
```

Then I restarted my system.  Then I launced compiz in the guake terminal as:

```
sudo compiz --replace
```

The `--replace` flag was required; apparently I already had a UI manager running.  After this, I simply right click on my guake terminal, go to **Preferences -->  Appearance --> Effects** and now adjusting the transparency works.